# PHP preg_replace any number starting with $ by xxx

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to replace every occurrence of $(any number) in text by xxx. E.g if there is occurrence of $923 in text then it should be xxx.

Patterns I have tried

```
                    $string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. $350 remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of $90 required Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

                    $pattern = '/^\$[0-9]+\.?[0-9]?[0-9]/i'; 

                    $pattern = '/($\[0-9]+)/';

                    $replacement = "xxx";
                    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$s = "$434 dsvsv $567 fsdgjfb";

echo preg_replace('/\$\d+/', 'xxx', $s);
```

**Output**

```
xxx dsvsv xxx fsdgjfb
```